# How get word started at specific character

Tags: java, regex

I have Arabic text and i need to edit document and replace some words start with "س" character using java codes.
for example
String s = "سالم يمشي في الغالبة";
output = لم يمشي في الغابة

Comment: Check out the javadoc of `String`.

Comment: Checkout the javadoc with "replace" as a keyword which you already mentioned in your question :)

Comment: Thanks for replaying, I want firstly find all words from text start with "س" then  get it make some check in it, after that i want to remvore char if condition true.

Answer (score 0):

this pattern works in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/184)

```
(?:\s|^)س\S+
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the "word boundary" pattern, `\b`.

```
newString = string.replaceAll("\\bس", "");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with this regular expression:

```
(?:\s|^)س\S+
```